# cell table in Dart?

Tags: dart

I need an editable table in Dart but I cannot find a good solution. There is some examples (http://igindo.com/dart/datagrid/dartPlay.html) but the cell is not editable.

The idea example I'm looking for is like gwt cell table
http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any editable tables in Dart yet. Soon, hopefully...